# Predicting survival probability at a fixed timepoint

Tags: survival, predictive-models

I'm attempting to build a model to predict 6 month survival probability in a cohort of lung cancer patients based on patient demographics (age, performance status, co-morbidity scores etc), tumour staging and treatment details.

Initially I thought the best approach would be to use a model (logistic regression, random forest, support vector machine etc.) which just predicts 6 month survival (and nothing else), as this must surely be easier to predict (less information) than the full survival curve as in the Cox model.

The disadvantage of this approach seems to be that the model misses out on the influence of subjects with a long overall survival time (i.e. the model does not know the difference between a patient who lives for 7 months vs 70 months) which may be important information in discriminating between early and late mortality patients. Additionally most approaches for modelling the probability of binary events are not built to handle time to event data and so cannot handle censoring.

What would be considered the "best" or most appropriate approach for survival prediction at a fixed timepoint?